# T-SQL COUNT of 'A', 'B', and 'A or B'

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Conceptually, I have a table with a list of fruit items.  I want, in a single query, to see counts of how many apples, oranges, 'apples or oranges', and 'other fruit' there are.

How can I achieve this in T-SQL?

Comment: As an example, your title and description both imply that you might have a row with a single value such as `'apples or oranges'`... based on @gbn's answer we can now assume that what you meant is not what you said, and each row will have a singular value such as `apple` or `orange` or `kiwi`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand The concepts in the data would have taken too much explanation.  I get your point, but fruit is universal, and was answered effectively.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If you look at my previous questions, almost all of those not marked with an answer were not correctly answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS Allfruits,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Apple' THEN 1 END) AS AppleCount,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit = 'Orange' THEN 1 END) AS OrangeCount,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit IN ('Apple','Orange') THEN 1 END) AS AppleOrOrangeCount,
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE WHEN fruit IN ('Apple','Orange') THEN 1 END) AS OtherFruitCount
FROM
   MyTable
```

Note: CASE gives NULL without an ELSE clause or some explicit condition. COUNT ignores NULL.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks!  The concept I had missed was to put a CASE inside a COUNT.  Don't think I've done that before.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out given a vague problem (at least to my eyes).